# Spring integrationflow test

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to test

```
 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inventoryImportInboundChannelAdapter,
            p -> p.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(inventoryImportJobProperties.getPollingFrequency()))).
            handle(fileMessageToPath()).
            handle(fileMessageToJobRequest()).
            handle(jobLaunchingGateway).
            log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "headers.id + ': ' + payload").
            get();
}
```

Inventory import channel adapter is s3 adapter, i dont want to connect to S3 for component test. I tried using MockIntegrationContext and it did not work . Please advise

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @SpringBootTest(classes = {ImportInventoryJobIntegrationFlow.class})
   @SpringIntegrationTest
   public class ImportInventoryJobIntegrationFlowTest {

    @MockBean
    private MessageSource<?> inventoryImportInboundChannelAdapter;
    @MockBean
    private Job inventoryImportJob;
    @MockBean
    private JobRepository jobrepository;
    @MockBean
    private InventoryImportJobProperties inventoryImportJobProperties;


    @Autowired
    private MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationContext;


    @Test
    public void testChannelAdapter(){
        File importFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
        BDDMockito.given(importFile.getParent()).willReturn("test.import");
        System.out.println(mockIntegrationContext);
        this.mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageSourceFor("inventoryImportInboundChannelAdapter",
                MockIntegration.mockMessageSource(importFile));

    }
}
```

Error getting is:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'inventoryImportInboundChannelAdapter' available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, refer to the `mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageSourceFor()` JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Replace the real {@link MessageSource} in the {@link SourcePollingChannelAdapter} bean
 * with provided {@link MessageSource} instance.
 * Can be a mock object.
 * @param pollingAdapterId the endpoint bean name
 * @param mockMessageSource the {@link MessageSource} to replace in the endpoint bean
 * @see org.springframework.integration.test.mock.MockIntegration#mockMessageSource
 */
public void substituteMessageSourceFor(String pollingAdapterId, MessageSource<?> mockMessageSource) {
```

The key word there is `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`. This bean is a result of your

```
IntegrationFlows.from(inventoryImportInboundChannelAdapter,
        p -> p.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(inventoryImportJobProperties.getPollingFrequency())))
```

Unfortunately you don't specify here that `inventoryImportInboundChannelAdapter`, so its target name is generated.

Consider to add `.id("inventoryImportInboundChannelAdapter")` before or after `poller()` definition for that endpoint.

**UPDATE**

We have a test configuration like this:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(() -> new GenericMessage<>("myData"),
                        e -> e.id("mySourceEndpoint"))
                .<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase)
                .channel(results())
                .get();
    }
```

Pay attention to the `e.id("mySourceEndpoint")` .
And then in the test we do like this:

```
this.mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageSourceFor("mySourceEndpoint",
            MockIntegration.mockMessageSource("foo", "bar", "baz"));
```

Comment: Added, p -> p.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(inventoryImportJobProperties.getPollingFrequency())).id("inventoryImportPoller")). still showing org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'inventoryImportPoller' available

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Please, show more stack trace for that `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

Comment: Never mind, I used a mockbean without name caused the issue.Thanks for your time and support

Comment: Yes, please . another note , @EnableIntegration was in main configuration class not on the config i loaded for this particular test

Comment: Huh? I've seen `@SpringBootTest` in your test, so decided that you are good with the configuration on the matter. Good to know that problem is solved! Only you can accept the answer since you are the requestor.

Comment: mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageSourceFor("inventoryImportPoller", messageSource); --> inventoryImportPoller is the fixedRate poller, and it produces many massages, is there a way to control it?

Comment: Well, not yet, but you can stop that channel Adapter altogether and create a new one with its one polling policy